# How to properly match file names in subdirectories?

Tags: haskell, recursion, name-matching

I am currently going through the book *Real World Haskell* and one exercise from this book asks the reader to implement file name matching with the use of `**`, which is the same as `*`, but also looks in subdirectories all the way down in the file system. Below is a fragment of my code with comments (there is a lot of duplication at the moment) and further down you can find additional info about the code. I think that the posted code is sufficient for the problem and there is no need to list the whole program here.

```
case splitFileName pat of
        ("", baseName) -> do -- just the file name passed
            curDir <- getCurrentDirectory
            if searchSubDirs baseName -- check if file name has `**` in it
              then do 
                  contents <- getDirectoryContents curDir
                  subDirs <- filterM doesDirectoryExist contents
                  let properSubDirs = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) subDirs
                  subDirsNames <- forM properSubDirs $ \dir -> do
                                      namesMatching (curDir </> dir </> baseName) -- call the function recursively on subdirectories
                  curDirNames <- listMatches curDir baseName -- list matches in the current directory
                  return (curDirNames ++ (concat subDirsNames)) -- concatenate results into a single list
              else listMatches curDir baseName
        (dirName, baseName) -> do // full path passed
            if searchSubDirs baseName
              then do
                  contents <- getDirectoryContents dirName
                  subDirs <- filterM doesDirectoryExist contents
                  let properSubDirs = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) subDirs
                  subDirsNames <- forM properSubDirs $ \dir -> do
                                      namesMatching (dirName </> dir </> baseName) -- call the function recursively on subdirectories
                  curDirNames <- listMatches dirName baseName -- list matches in the passed directory
                  return (curDirNames ++ (concat subDirsNames)) -- concatenate results into a single list
```

### Additional information:

`pat` is the pattern I'm looking for (e.g. `*.txt` or `C:\\A\[a-z].*`).

`splitFileName` is a function which splits a file path into the directory path and the file name. The first element of the tuple will be empty if we specify just a file name in `pat`.

`searchSubDirs` returns `True` if the file name has `**` in it.

`listMatches` returns a list of file names that match the pattern in the directory, substituting `**` for `*`.

`namesMatching` is the name of the function whose excerpt I posted.

### Why doesn't it work?

When I pass just the file name, the program searches for it only in the current directory and first level of subdirectories. When I pass a full path, it searches only in the specified directory. It looks like case `(dirName, baseName)` doesn't properly recurse. I've been looking at the code for some time now and I can't figure out where the problem is.

### Note

If any more information is needed, please let me know in the comments and I'll add whatever is necessary to the question.

Comment: Do the `//` comments work for you???

Comment: @ErikR Oh, I just added them here in C# style. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an issue:

```
              contents <- getDirectoryContents dirName
              subDirs <- filterM doesDirectoryExist contents
```

`getDirectoryContents` only returns the leaf names of the directories, so you have to prepend `dirName` (along with a `/`) to the elements of `contents` before calling `doesDirectoryExist`.